# NoSuchElementException when using Scanner

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

This code is calculator for prifix.
first input means number of line to calculate,
and then input expression.

e.g)
2\n
12+3*\n
31/2-4*2+\n

And It works well in eclipse but did not work in scoring site.
Scoring site said that

> Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException Maybe at: at
>   Calculation.main(Calculation.java:16)
>
> line 16 is 'String string=scan2.nextLine();'

But I cannot find out where is wrong.

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Calculation{

        public static void main(String[] args){

            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            Scanner scan1=new Scanner(System.in);
            int n=scan1.nextInt();

            ArrayList<String> input=new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

                System.out.print("Enter a expression in postfix: ");
                Scanner scan2=new Scanner(System.in);
                String string=scan2.nextLine();
                input.add(i,string);

            }

            Stack<Integer> stack=new Stack<Integer>();

            for(int i=0;i<=input.size()-1;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<=input.get(i).length()-1;j++){
                    if(input.get(i).charAt(j)>=48&&input.get(i).charAt(j)<=57)
                        stack.push(Integer.parseInt(input.get(i).valueOf(input.get(i).charAt(j))));
                    else{
                        int n2=stack.pop();
                        int n1=stack.pop();

                        if(input.get(i).charAt(j)=='+')
                            stack.push(n1+n2);
                        if(input.get(i).charAt(j)=='-')
                            stack.push(n1-n2);
                        if(input.get(i).charAt(j)=='/')
                            stack.push(n1/n2);
                        if(input.get(i).charAt(j)=='*')
                            stack.push(n1*n2);          
                    }   

                }

                int output=stack.pop();
                System.out.println(output);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Is the scoring site using test-cases for checking your algorithm or is it just an online compiler?

Comment: Don't open more than one scanner for the same input stream. And pay attention to [clearing the scanner after `nextInt`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/4125191).

Answer (score 0):

the thing is when you use

```
String str=scan1.nextLine();
```

it will only read your input until space after that it won't so to read a string input just use

```
String str=scan1.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Read a full line to stay in sync with line endings. Don't use another scanner.

```
  int n=scan1.nextInt();
  scan1.nextLine();
  ArrayList<String> input=new ArrayList<String>();
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       System.out.print("Enter a expression in postfix: ");
       String string=scan1.nextLine();
       input.add(i,string);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `scan2.nextLine();` previous line break after `nextInt()` was not processed that's why that newline character still in buffer got read through your `scan2.nextLine()` instead of your new input.

You can handle it two ways -

1. Do an empty `scan1.nextLine()` immediately after that first `nextInt()` call.
2. or Instead of using `nextInt()`, use `nextLine()` and using `Integer.parseInt()` convert that string to integer.